# In c#, what are the rules for defining a pure method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna

Is this simple extension method for a rectangle for example pure?

If not, why not?
And if it is, why?

```
    [Pure]
    public static Rectangle InflateCopy(this Rectangle r, float horizontal, float vertical)
    {
        r.X -= (int)horizontalAmount;
        r.Y -= (int)verticalAmount;
        r.Width += (int)horizontalAmount*2;
        r.Height += (int)verticalAmount*2;
        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [Wikipedia - Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> In computer programming, a function may be considered a pure function if both below statements about the function hold:
>
> 1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices (usually—see below).

The [Microsoft documentation for the PureAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) states this:

> Indicates that a type or method is pure, that is, it does not make any visible state changes.

Microsofts description of what a pure method is is somewhat shorter and is missing one key piece, the fact that a pure method should always evaluate to the same result given the same input arguments.

So is your method pure?

1. If you feed it the same rectangle and the same other argument values, it will always generate the same output, it does not use any other variables or information than what was provided to it through parameters.
2. Assuming that your usage of `Rectangle` is [System.Drawing.Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a `struct`, then even though the method appears to be changing the rectangle it is only changing its own private copy of it, and thus you will not see any observable side effects of this method.
3. It does not use or change state (state is considered everything external to the argument values).

So yes, this method is pure.

Comment: _"Assuming that your usage of Rectangle is System.Drawing.Rectangle"_ - OP is using XNA so it's  `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle`.  It's a struct anyway ;)